# How to perform an HTTP redirect (302) using Rack?

Tags: ruby, http, rack

I am messing around with my first Rack application (this is just for experimentation).

When a call comes in I do something like this:

```
class Application
    def call(env)
      # Totally ignore favicons for the time being
      if env['PATH_INFO'] == '/favicon.ico'
        return [ 404, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, [] ]
      elsif env['PATH_INFO'] == '/'
        return [ 302, {'http-equiv' => "refresh", 'content' => "2;url=http://google.com"}, [] ]
      end
      ...
```

I know this is horrible... but, again, this isn't a serious project.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the redirect. What I have does not work. Basically, when you hit / on my site I want to redirect that require to google.com.

Comment: There are two `end` missing in your program.  It does not compile without those

Comment: It was not my intention to have it be compilable (you can't test it in isolation anyway). My intension was to signify that there is elided code with the use of ellipses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is working app with re-direct to Google

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'

class HelloWorld
  def response
    [ 302, {'Location' =>"http://google.com"}, [] ]
  end
end

class HelloWorldApp
  def self.call(env)
    HelloWorld.new.response
  end
end

Rack::Server.start :app => HelloWorldApp
```